# All the NSTableView in my project don't receive the space bar keyboard event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

A NSTableView doesn't receive the space bar keyboard event.

When I press keyUp or keyDown the selection changes correctly, but I'm not able to check/uncheck the checkbox in the first column by pressing the space bar.

Since the arrow keys work correctly, I assume the events are correctly received by the NSTableView.

Also, I've just checked for any delegate method in my code, that could interfere:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)handleEvent:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)event;
```

and commented them out, but the space bar still doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually found out the reason. It is not true that the space bar is checking the table items by default.

It works only if Systems Preferences > Keyboard > KeyBoard Shortcuts > All Controls radio button is selected.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to check is that the type select feature is not eating your spacebar presses. I've seen this problem in the past. You should be able to call `[yourTableView setAllowsTypeSelect:NO]` to turn it off. However, for some reason, in one case the only way I was able to successfully get around this was to implement the NSTableViewDelegate method `-tableView:typeSelectStringForTableColumn:row:` and return nil:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView typeSelectStringForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return nil;
}
```

This will disable type select all together. In my case that was fine. As explained in the documentation:

> Return nil if the row or tableColumn should not be searched.

The other option might be to implement `-tableView:shouldTypeSelectForEvent:withCurrentSearchString:` and return NO if the event's keyCode is 49 (spacebar). That way type select remains enabled, it's only the spacebar that gets ignored.

This is just one idea. It may not actually be what's causing your problem, but I've seen identical symptoms in the past, and type select was the cause.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all those solutions. I've implemented all of them, I'm sure the delegate methods you suggested are invoked, and I've also disabled type selection (in the interface builder). But I can't check the checkbox yet. Maybe the problem is somewhere else ?

Comment: Since I have the same issue with all tables in my project, is maybe some general setting ?